# Ajax live search, "No products found" when the title contains apostrophes and quotations

Tags: ajax, search

my website theme has an Ajax search bar.  My search bar does not seem to work properly when searching for products containing apostrophes and quotes in the title.

Example:

Title of a product is **4'x4' Grow Tent** I will type 4' into my live search bar, and when I click on the actual product that shows up in the dropdown live search bar, I am directed to a page saying "No products found".

Any ideas? I've been searching for days with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply some function like [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.htmlspecialchars.php) on your query before searching for it, it will translate your special chars into HTML entities.

Comment: Escaping will also increase the security of your code.